# How to set text in div block to have a specific width?

Tags: html, css, web, css-float

I am struggling to get the text in my code to only fill 80% width of my body element. Not sure if I should use the width element or padding.. Neither is working for me right now.

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="full">
            <h3>
                The Idea
            </h3>
            <p class="paragraph">
                text
            </p>
            <h3>
                A Very Profitable Investment
            </h3>
            <p class="paragraph">
                text
            </p>
            <h3>
                30 Years Experience
            </h3>
            <p class="paragraph">
                text
            </p>    
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
    #full{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#full {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

The above works perfectly fine for me

An element with the `display` property set to `inline-block` can't be automatically centered with an auto margin (hence why you may have perceived a full-width usage) but the width was actually already correct

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `display: block` then use `display: block; margin: 0 auto`, with `display: inline-block` you can remove `margin: ...` and use `padding: 0 10%` (10% padding on either side of the text = 20%)